# UserPrincipal.Current.Context fails for non-Administators

Tags: .net, security, userprincipal

The following line of code in my C#, .NET 5.0 Windows application throws an exception when my application runs normally but not when it runs as Administrator.

```
var pc  = UserPrincipal.Current.Context;
```

The message in the exception is "The server could not be contacted".  I am unable to determine the exact type of the exception because this is happening in the field and I'm looking at a log file which sadly fails to log that detail.  I have been unable to reproduce this myself.  So I'm looking for some "defensive programming" to hopefully get around it.

Is this something that I can make work without running as Administrator?  Is there some "safer" way to try to get the current context?  The only reason I'm trying to get it in the first place is to get a "friendly" name for the current user.  Like `UserPrincipal.DisplayName` or `UserPrincipal.Surname`?

When I run normally. this is the stack frame of the exception

```
09:26:21.799 [ 1] ERROR - RegisterTypes: Exception Registering types: The server could not be contacted.
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ReadServerConfig(String serverName, ServerProperties& properties)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoServerVerifyAndPropRetrieval()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext..ctor(ContextType contextType, String name, String container, ContextOptions options, String userName, String password)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext..ctor(ContextType contextType)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.get_Current()
   at MyApp.Services.SystemService.Initialize()
   at MyApp.Mobile.App.RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry reg)
```

Comment: I know this is old, but when you say "in the field", does that mean that the computer is not connected to the network? When a `UserPrincipal` object is created, it tries to go out to the domain controller to load the user's properties. That error is saying that it cannot reach the server.

Comment: By "in the field", I meant that it was happening on the computer of a customer:  That is, on a computer I could not physically access.  All I had was the log file.  Fortunately for me, the code path was not critical.  It was just trying to determine the user-friendly name of the user.   If we cannot determine that, we can still get our job done.  So I wrapped the code in an exception block and issued a fix.  I think the root issue was that it was a domain setup and our code did not have permission to access that data but I never bothered to investigate further